# Python program only appears when I press enter

Tags: python

When I run a program with the IDLE already open, it sometimes needs me to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the text to appear.

How do I make this go away?

Code:

```
import random

def var():

    dice_score = 0
    repeat = ""
    dicesides = input("Please enter the amount of sides you want the dice to have.\n The amounts you can have are as follows: 4, 6 or 12: ")
    script(dice_score, dicesides, repeat)

def script(dicescore, dicesides, repeat):

    if dicesides in [4,6,12]:
        dice_score = random.randrange(1, dicesides)
        print(dicesides, " sided dice, score ", dice_score, "\n")
    else:
        print("Please Try Again. \n")
        var()
    repeat = str(input("Repeat? Simply put yes or no: ").lower())

    if repeat == "yes":
        var()
    else:
        quit()

var()
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you need answer or whatever, please include the relevant information.

Comment: There is no information, when I run my python script, I need to press enter for it to appear.

Comment: What is the code that you are running? Seems like you are waiting for an extra input of some sort when program runs.

Comment: I have edited the question so the code is in it.

Comment: Is this Python 2.x? Or 3? Please specify.

Comment: Do you have a new line character after last line?

Answer (score 0):

You must always try to include whatever user input variable your function requires in the function itself! Also, you forgot to type-cast `dicesides` to `int` because `input()` returns a string. Also, IMO, the function parameters are pretty useless, you could ask for them in the function itself.

I would do it in the following way.

```
from random import randrange

def script():

    dicesides = int(input("Please enter the amount of sides you want the dice to have.\n The amounts you can have are as follows: 4, 6 or 12: "))

    if dicesides in [4,6,12]:
        dice_score = randrange(1, dicesides)
        print(dicesides, " sided dice, score ", dice_score, "\n")
        return True
    else:
        print("Please Try Again. \n")
        return False

repeat = "yes"
yes = ["yes", "y", "YES", "Y"]

while repeat in yes:
    if not script():
        continue
    repeat = input("Repeat? Simply put yes or no: ").lower()
```

As for the main question `needing an extra enter`, I don't get you. With the above code, that won't happen anyway.